# How to change values in a column based on a function applied on two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

So i have a data frame DF that looks like this:
DF:

```
match_id        team        teamA_Win  Outcome
1               A           True        None
2               B           True        None
3               A           False       None
```

The outcome column in this df is filled with the string 'None'

What i want is to be able to change the value of the string in outcome to either 'Win' or 'Loss' based on the values in team and teamA_win.

As an example, if the Team == A and TeamA_win=True is True, then the outcome should be Win. However if Team==A and TeamA_Win=False then the outcome is Loss. Similarly if Team==B and TeamA_Win=True then the outcome should be Loss.

I created the following function:

```
def win(x):
    if (x['team']=='A')& (x['teamA_win']==True):
        x['outcome']='Win'
    elif ((x['team']=='A')& (x['teamA_win']==False)):
        x['outcome']='Loss'
    elif ((x['team']=='B')& (x['teamA_win']==True)):
        x['outcome']='Loss'    
    elif ((x['team']=='B')& (x['teamA_win']==False)):
        x['outcome']='Win'
```

Now however when i invoke win(DF), i get the error:
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Any idea on how to fix this? or if there is a simpler way to approach this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or a two-liner, make `'Outcome'` column `False`, and use `loc` to check if `'team'` column equals to `'teamA_Win'` replace `True` with `'A'` and `False` with `'B'`, if it does, make the `'Outcome'` column `True`:

```
df['Outcome']=False
df.loc[df['team']==df['teamA_Win'].map({True:'A',False:'B'}),'Outcome']=True
```

Output:

```
   match_id team teamA_Win Outcome
0         1    A      True    True
1         2    B      True   False
2         3    A     False   False
```

Comment: This worked out aswell! I just cant wrap my head around the problem with the code i wrote and what was causing it to not work as it seems to be logically valid

Comment: @ShahAbbas Because you where doing `win(DF)`, which processes the whole data at once, so if you do: `DF.apply(win,axis=1)` it will work, this goes row by row, so every row will get the `win` function for calculation.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate the clarification!

Comment: @ShahAbbas Happy to help, :-), 

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `np.select`, which will allow you to define your conditions and their possible values, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def win(x):
    conditions = [
        (x['team']=='A') & (x['teamA_win']==True),
        (x['team']=='A') & (x['teamA_win']==False),
        (x['team']=='B') & (x['teamA_win']==True),
        (x['team']=='B') & (x['teamA_win']==False)]

    choices = ['Win', 'Loss', 'Loss', 'Win']

    x['outcome'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You're calculating masks multiple times, and comparing a boolean series with a boolean value, you should cache results and make use of truthiness.

Comment: This actually worked! Would you be able to tell me how this code actually works? or what was wrong with my code that caused the error to display? Thank you